# Searchable Plugin Unable to Resolve Class in Grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails, searchable, grails-searchable

Whenever I run my Grails application for the first time, using searchable 0.6.4, I get the following error:

```
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\Users\starryknight64\.grails\2.2.4\projects\myapp\plugins\searchable-0.6.4\.\SearchableGrailsPlugin.groovy: 25: unable to resolve class org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDevice
 @ line 25, column 1.
   import org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDevice
   ^

C:\Users\starryknight64\.grails\2.2.4\projects\myapp\plugins\searchable-0.6.4\.\SearchableGrailsPlugin.groovy: 26: unable to resolve class org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
 @ line 26, column 1.
   import org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
   ^

2 errors
 (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\Users\starryknight64\.grails\2.2.4\projects\myapp\plugins\searchable-0.6.4\.\SearchableGrailsPlugin.groovy: 25: unable to resolve class org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDevice
 @ line 25, column 1.
   import org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDevice
   ^

C:\Users\starryknight64\.grails\2.2.4\projects\myapp\plugins\searchable-0.6.4\.\SearchableGrailsPlugin.groovy: 26: unable to resolve class org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
 @ line 26, column 1.
   import org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
   ^

2 errors

    at RunApp$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(RunApp:62)
    at RunApp$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(RunApp)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at RunApp.withCompilationErrorHandling(RunApp:69)
    at RunApp.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(RunApp)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
    at RunApp$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(RunApp:61)
    at RunApp$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(RunApp)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at RunApp$_run_closure3.doCall(RunApp:58)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at RunApp$_run_closure2.doCall(RunApp:45)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
    at RunApp$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(RunApp:42)
    at RunApp$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(RunApp)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at RunApp$_run_closure2.doCall(RunApp:41)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:30)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\Users\starryknight64\.grails\2.2.4\projects\myapp\plugins\searchable-0.6.4\.\SearchableGrailsPlugin.groovy: 25: unable to resolve class org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDevice
 @ line 25, column 1.
   import org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDevice
   ^

C:\Users\starryknight64\.grails\2.2.4\projects\myapp\plugins\searchable-0.6.4\.\SearchableGrailsPlugin.groovy: 26: unable to resolve class org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
 @ line 26, column 1.
   import org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
   ^

2 errors
```

Attempting to run the application a second time results in the application running as expected.

Not a showstopper, but certainly troublesome, any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Comment: Haven't gotten to try your solution yet. I meant to do it right after you posted the work-around but simply haven't yet.

Comment: Shouldn't the searchable plugin be buildable right out of the gate? Or is this something we should be expecting to do for every plugin?

Comment: "buildable out of the gate" what did you mean exactly?

Comment: By "buildable out of the gate" I mean the plugin should be compilable immediately with little or no configuration necessary. It appears searchable is an exception in that the build must first be "primed" before it can be built.

Comment: use following repository
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe you need to run `grails refresh-dependencies` after the plugin is added in `BuildConfig.groovy` but before `run-app`.

This would help in refreshing the dependencies of the app to those two files which are present in `lib` of the plugin.

`searchable-0.6.4/lib/compass-2.2.1.jar`.

As those dependencies are not configured in dependency section in the `BuildConfig` of the plugin but in `lib`, hence `refresh-dependencies` command is required.

It works in subsequent attempts because once the app is compiled or run, app becomes cognizant of the transitive dependencies it needs to pull from the plugin.

Comment: Thanks it did worked after giving `grails refresh-dependencies`

Comment: This does work for me, however, this seems to be a bit of a work-around. My expectation for using a plugin is that it builds with minimal configuration. Since searchable requires little to no configuration, I'd expect it to build right away, without having to "prime" the build before-hand.

Answer (score 8):

I have need to add a couple of maven repos in BuildConfig.groovy

```
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
mavenRepo "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
```

And then:

```
grails compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies
```

Tested on grails 2.3.7